# Who should keep DisposeBag in MVVM(+controller) on swift

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I try to develop iOS app with RxSwift + MVVM architecture.
I have a question. Who should have DisposeBag instance?
Now, I am implementing as the following in my code.

- View model has a instance of "Variable".
- Controller keep the DisposeBag.
- View subscribes to observable of view model and attach controller's dispose bag.

Is it good design or not?
I want to have code standard, please give me your opinion.

Answer (score 6):

The DisposeBag needs to be where the side effects happen. Side effects shouldn't happen in your view model, it should merely transform input into output. Therefore the DisposeBag should be in the View Controller.

Comment: but should we transfer view controller's dispose bag to view model ?

Comment: No. If properly designed, the view model has no need of a dispose bag. Disposables are generated upon subscription and the subscriptions will all be in the view controller, not the view model.